# FirebaseDatabase query issues in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I am currently working on a clone like snapchat and I am sending pull requests to the server, but as for downloading, it is not going so well. I created a reference to the database that looks like this,

```
var recievers: FIRDatabaseReference{
    return mainRef.child("pullRequests")
}
```

and then I have a viewController that parses the data (which I know isn't the best way to go about this but I'm just trying to get it working right now) and in there I have this

```
    DataService.instance.recievers.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) {(recipients: FIRDataSnapshot) in
        if let recipient = recipients.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>{
            var index = 0;
            for(key,value) in recipient{
                index = index+1
                if let dict = value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>{
                    if let reciever = dict["recipents"] as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>{
                        if let num = reciever["\(index)"] as? String{
                            let uid = num
                            recipientsArr.append(uid)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    for i in 0...recipientsArr.count{
    print(i)
    }
```

I'm not getting any compiling errors but it is also not adding anything into the recipientsArr, can anyone help guide me in the right direction?

My Firebase looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not decoding the snapshot properly. Its unclear from your question what is the value event you want to observe - is it just a new recipient that was added? the whole pullRequest?
In any case you're observing the pullRequest reference and therefore in order to decode the snapshot:

```
    if let pullRequest = recipients.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>{
          if let recipientsList = pullRequest["recipents"] as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>{
               for (_, value) in recipientsList {
                    if let uid = value as? String{
                        recipientsArr.append(uid)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: I am trying to read in just the recipents elements  "tLvt...", "JqIr.." etc. to put in the the recipientsArr, I tried your method as well and it led to the same result. It seems like nothing is being added to the array

Comment: Have your run the debugger to see where in the snapshot decoding its failing? Just to make sure  - is the callback for ObserveSingleEvent even called?If you want to read changes to the recipients list it would be better to choose this as your reference to observe: mainRef.child("pullRequests").child("recipents")

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the method `observeSingleEvent` to update the value in the database, when this method is only used to recieve data from the database, not updated. In other words, it read-only.

The way to update record in a firebase database works different than the read methods. You can use both methods `setValue` and `updateChildValues` to perform updates. They both work on a database reference.

To use the `setValue` method, you should do something like this. I'll assume that you already have a pullRequests object that you previously created from the information you fetched from the database and have it in a variable:

```
let previousRecipents = pullRequests.recipents
let allRecipents = previousRecipents.append(newRecipent) // Assuming preivousRecipents is an array and you have the new Recipent
recievers.child("recipents").setValue(allRecipents)
```

To use the `updateChildValues`, it works very similar.

```
let previousRecipents = pullRequests.recipents
let allRecipents = previousRecipents.append(newRecipent) // Assuming preivousRecipents is an array and you have the new Recipent
let parametersToUpdate = ["recipents": allRecipents]
recievers.updateChildValues(parametersToUpdate)
```

For further information on how to update, check the following link:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/save-data

Hope it helps!

Comment: I dont have problem updating the database, I'm trying to get pull the recipents array of uid's out of the database